# Python: a set of doors that can be painted simultaneously or separately

Tags: python, class, getter-setter

I have to create a code that has set of doors and they can be called to be painted simulateneously or seperately. I have managed to create the code but I need advice on what exact code I need to add in order to change all of the door's colour.

Here is the code:

```
class Door:
    colour = 'brown'

    def __init__(self, number, status):
        self.number = number
        self.status = status

    @classmethod
    def knock(cls):
        print("Knock!")

    @classmethod
    def paint(cls, colour):
        cls.colour = colour

    def open(self):
        self.status = 'opened'

    def close(self):
        self.status = 'closed'


class Door2:
    colour = 'yellow'

    def __init__(self, number, status):
        self.number = number
        self.status = status

    @classmethod
    def knock(cls):
        print("Knock!")

    @classmethod
    def paint(cls, colour):
        cls.colour = colour

    def open(self):
        self.status = 'opened'

    def close(self):
        self.status = 'closed'


class Door3:
    colour = 'green'

    def __init__(self, number, status):
        self.number = number
        self.status = status

    @classmethod
    def knock(cls):
        print("Knock!")

    @classmethod
    def paint(cls, colour):
        cls.colour = colour

    def open(self):
        self.status = 'opened'

    def close(self):
        self.status = 'closed'


class Door4:
    colour = 'red'

    def __init__(self, number, status):
        self.number = number
        self.status = status

    @classmethod
    def knock(cls):
        print("Knock!")

    @classmethod
    def paint(cls, colour):
        cls.colour = colour

    def open(self):
        self.status = 'opened'

    def close(self):
        self.status = 'closed'


door1 = Door(1, 'closed')
door2 = Door2(2, 'closed')
door3 = Door3(1, 'closed')
door4 = Door4(2, 'closed')


print(door1.colour)
print(door2.colour)
print(door3.colour)
print(door4.colour)
```

The output right now:

```
brown
yellow
green
red
```

Comment: `door1.paint("red")`, `door2.paint("blue")` etc.?

Comment: What is the expected outcome?

Comment: 99% of those classes are identical, only the colour is different. For that you either want to define one base class and inherit from it so you're not repeating those 99% of code; or you make `color` an *instance attribute* instead of a class attribute, so you just need one `Door` class to begin with…

Comment: I'm suppose to call a code where I paint all of the doors the same color instead of calling each door separetely.

Comment: @deceze could you please help write the exact code becuase i'm very new to this and not sure where exactly to add it and what to type

Comment: Still need help on what exactly to write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The door colour should be exactly the same kind of thing as its open/closed status: an instance attribute. That eliminates the need to repeat the same class definition four times just for the different colours:

```
class Door:
    def __init__(self, number, status, color):
        self.number = number
        self.status = status
        self.color = color

    def knock(self):
        print('Knock!')

    def paint(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def open(self):
        self.status = 'opened'

    def close(self):
        self.status = 'closed'
```

Now just make a list of doors:

```
doors = [Door(1, 'closed', 'brown'), Door(2, 'closed', 'yellow'), ...]
```

Then paint them all in a loop:

```
for door in doors:
    print(door.color)
    door.paint('red')
    print(door.color)
```